# Android zoomable view with pin

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, pinchzoom, android-gesture

I'm looking for tips or a lib that can help me with this challenge: I need to build a widget that is similar to a Map View. I mean, I have a huge image that will be used as background and a list of coordinates that should be used as pins over the image.

I need to achieve an experience similar to a Map View (pan, zoom and pinch gestures) and treat pin clicks. Once placed over the image, a pin should note move its position considering the background image.

The problem is not really new, but I couldn't solve it yet. I've tried a WebView with some html but the image is rendered really blurry.

Any tip? Any Github project? I've googled a lot and found no answer.